# does not name a type error that is really annoying

Tags: c++, struct

```
#include<iostream>



class Grafo
{ 
  public:

    struct noArco
  { int elem;
    noArco *next;
    noArco *head;
  }; 



  noArco *array; 
  int numVertices;
  Grafo();
  ~Grafo();
  noArco novoNo(int val);
  void insereSucessor(int v, int elem);
  void removeSucessor(int v, int elem);
  void listarSucessor(int vertice);          
};     





#include"Grafo.h"
using namespace std;
Grafo::Grafo()  
{
  for(int i=0 ; i<numVertices ; i++)

   {  array[i].head=NULL;                      
   }
}

    Grafo::~Grafo(){}

noArco Grafo::novoNo(int val)
{ noArco *novo = new noArco;
  novo->elem = val;
  novo->next = NULL;
  return novo;
  };


void Grafo::insereSucessor(int v, int elem)
{}

void Grafo::removeSucessor(int v, int elem)
{}

void Grafo::listarSucessor(int vertice)
{}
```

I saw several of errors like this here, but those couldnt help me unfortunately. 
when i compile this code it gives me an error of: "noArco does not name a type"
 I would like to know where is my mistake here

Comment: -1 for not making any attempt to narrow the problem down.

Comment: Is it fair to conclude that the OP did not make this attempt?

Comment: no Jordan, I had tried this attempt, but it was giving another error, but i solved it know. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `noArco` is a *nested* type, so its full name is `Grafo::noArco`:

```
Grafo::noArco Grafo::novoNo(int val)
//^^^^^
{
    noArco *novo = new noArco;
    novo->elem = val;
    novo->next = NULL;
    return novo;
};
```

Comment: ohh, thats true, after putting it this way i got another error, because of my pointers, but solved it now, thank you kerrek SB

Comment: @IvanKiritGeentilal: OK. In the future, try narrowing your problems down until you're where exactly they occur, so you can make  a concise question... good luck.